# Allow to close a question as a duplicate using a question from another Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, site-crossover

At the moment at Stack Overflow if I try to vote to close a question as a duplicate I have to choose an existing question from Stack Overflow. If I try to choose an existing question at another Stack Exchange site the system doesn't allow it. Could this limitation be removed?

Here is one specific example.

I have seen a lot of questions on Stack Overflow under [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag asking how to retrieve the first N rows per group in [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server). It is a common problem and there are several ways to do it. There is a great question with comprehensive answers for this question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/: [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86415/57105).

I think that a lot of people who ask this question at Stack Overflow would benefit greatly if they read the answer at dba.se.

I've seen many times that such questions at Stack Overflow get several short answers within few minutes. Usually answers are correct, but nobody bothers explaining other possible approaches and which method is better in which case. I was giving such answers myself. Since the question often doesn't have enough details to recommend a specific method, people get a generic answer, which works, but may be far from optimal solution. I think that closing such questions as duplicates using excellent detailed answers would be better.

Comment: **Not** a duplicate, since the purported duplicated question asks about closing against _off site_ duplicates, while this question asks about closing against duplicates on another stack, both part of the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 11):

It's long been allowed to ask the same question on different sites. The expectation is that the context of the site will yield different correct answers.

Answer (score 4):

> I have seen a lot of questions on SO under sql tag asking how to
>   retrieve first N rows per group in SQL Server.

Those should be getting closed as a duplicate to an existing answered SO question. You can provide your own answer to which ever question is the duplicate target on Stack Overflow and include a link to the DBA question.

After that it should just be a matter of closing the other questions as dupes when you see them.

Comment: I see. I thought that it is not a good idea to replicate a question from another site.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - I don't think you should do it on purpose, I just don't think it's a good idea to expect users to check multiple SE sites before asking a question.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this guys:

- The [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246189/how-to-delete-all-files-with-lftp-except-for-cgi-bin-and-ftpquota/58253476#58253476) Question:
- The Question [on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119458/lftp-mirror-to-remote-except-particular-file-present-on-remote):

> Why I cannot mark it as duplicated? I'm really in the middle of "copying" an answer just to redirect the user by myself to another place... is a little of strange.
>
> Why In the options for marking it as off topic, there is also not
> option for another stack exchange network?